# When you close intent by hardware back button, this freeze the application

Tags: android, delphi, android-intent, zxing, delphi-xe6

I created an Android application with Delphi XE6 and I used the code found on the internet, to connect to ZXing BarCode Scanner.

In a new project that only uses this code, everything works normally!

If I add several `TabControl`, `ToolBar`, `Label`, `Edit`, `Button` and other standard components, this happens to me:

1. ZXing start properly and if I scan a barcode back to my application regularly.
2. If I close ZXing with the hardware back button, ZXing closes but the application is frozen with a black screen.

With debugging the application does not seem to stop. The return code is corrected and the flow continues until the end, without giving any error.

The calling code is:

```
function TZXing.ZXingScan: Boolean;
var
  Intent: JIntent;
  ResolveInfo: JResolveInfo;
begin
  Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init( StringToJString( 'com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN' ) );
  Intent.setPackage( StringToJString( 'com.google.zxing.client.android' ) );
  Intent.putExtra( StringToJString( 'SAVE_HISTORY' ), False );
  ResolveInfo := SharedActivity.getPackageManager.resolveActivity( Intent, 0 );
  Result := ResolveInfo <> nil;
  if Result then
    SharedActivity.startActivityForResult( Intent, 0 );
end;
```

The callback procedure code is:

```
procedure TZXing.OnZXingResult( RequestCode, ResultCode: Integer; Data: JIntent );
begin
  TMessageManager.DefaultManager.Unsubscribe( TMessageResultNotification, FMessageSubscriptionID );
  FMessageSubscriptionID := 0;
  if ( RequestCode = 0 ) and Assigned( FResultProcedure ) then
  begin
    if ResultCode = TJActivity.JavaClass.RESULT_OK then
    begin
      if Assigned( Data ) then
        Result := ( OK, JStringToString( Data.getStringExtra( StringToJString( 'SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT') ) ), JStringToString( Data.getStringExtra( StringToJString( 'SCAN_RESULT' ) ) ) )
      else
        Result := ERROR;
    end else if ResultCode = TJActivity.JavaClass.RESULT_CANCELED then
      Result := CANCELED;
  end;
end;
```

I've tried everything and tried everything but I can not find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem maybe is in the method where you handle the backbutton. Here is my code for the backbutton:

```
procedure TFrmBezoekverslag.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
var
  FService: IFMXVirtualKeyboardService;
begin
  if Key = vkHardwareBack then
  begin
      TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService
        (IFMXVirtualKeyboardService, IInterface(FService));
      if (FService <> nil) and (TVirtualKeyboardState.Visible
        in FService.VirtualKeyBoardState) then
      begin
        // Back button pressed, keyboard visible, so do nothing...
      end
      else
      begin
        // Back button pressed, keyboard not visible or not supported on this platform
        // Here you handle the code too close ZXING
        Key := 0; //If you don't want the form too close you need too add key=0
      end;
  end;
end;
```

If this doesn't help the problem probably is somewhere in the formClose method if you have that.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your result code is `null` as the called `Activity` has to explicitly set that.
Try overriding `onBackPressed()` to set the result code to "Cancelled" before calling through to `super`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response! 

I have already created the event with this code: 

CanClose := MessageDlg( SCanClose, TMsgDlgType.mtConfirmation, [ TMsgDlgBtn.mbYes, TMsgDlgBtn.mbNo ], - 1 ) = mrYes;

If i don't use this code, when I close ZXing, my app close also.

Comment: if ( RequestCode = 0 ) is most likely the issue. are you sure you have a valid RequestCode at that point?

Comment: Actually I just followed all the examples that lead on the internet. 
Also I not understand why with an application that has only the use of XZing everything works regularly!